# VBS Script to Replace a file if its modified date does not match stated date

Tags: vbscript, date-difference

I have the following script that will copy a file from one location to another, but what I require is for the script to only run if the modified date does not match the date that is stated in the vb script.

I have attempted to use `DateDiff` but can't get it work. This is the simple script I have so far, which will overwrite regardless:

```vb
dim filesys 
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If filesys.FileExists("C:\test1\test.txt") Then 
    filesys.CopyFile "C:\test1\test.txt", "C:\test2\" 
End If
```

How do I check for the file modified-date and compare it with another date before starting the copying process?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in regards to the problem you're facing with date comparison. The code you posted is irrelevant to the problem. You should include a) how you used `DateDiff` b) what the _"stated date"_ really means, is it a variable or you pass it as a CMD argument? etc. c) Is your problem not being able to compare the two dates or you can't get the file modified-date in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the date modified and one possible way to compare as strings since you want to see if the dates are not equal.

```
dim filesys 
set filesys=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

Dim sFilespec
sFilespec = "C:\test1\test.txt"

If filesys.FileExists(sFilespec) Then 
  ' Get DateCreated
  dateModified = FormatDateTime(ShowFileInfo(sFilespec),2)
  dateStated = FormatDateTime(Now(),2)

  Debug.WriteLine("Modified: " & FormatDateTime(dateModified,2))
  Debug.WriteLine("  Stated: " & FormatDateTime(dateStated,2))
  Debug.WriteLine("")

  ' 
  If dateModified <> dateStated Then
    Debug.WriteLine dateModified & " is not equal to " & dateStated
    filesys.CopyFile sFilespec, "C:\test2\" 
  Else
    Debug.WriteLine dateModified & " is equal to " & dateStated
  End If
End If  


' Get the date last modified
Function ShowFileInfo(filespec)
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.GetFile(filespec)
   ShowFileInfo = f.DateLastModified
End Function
```